# MongoDB aggregation vs using javascript function performance

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, chart.js

I'm trying to figure out what the preferred way of generating data for my chartjs chart is. The data is in MongoDB. I have two options for creating the object to provide the data for the chart.

1. Use mongoose to aggregate the data that I want.
2. Use mongoose to find the data then, transform it into what I need.

Is there a standard way of doing this? I'm just looking for the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Aggregation is almost always more efficient

Comment: Cool. Thanks, @AlexBlex.

Comment: Any queries, like aggregation, are composed on the client application and are executed on the MongoDB Server. It is efficient that the processing done on the server and you get a result on the client. On the other hand, getting all the data from the server to the client is a lot of connection time, network usage, etc (resources).